# zsh prompt adam2 - script output without newline, is not being displayed

Tags: bash, unix, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm using **adam2** prompt on **iterm2** terminal on mac for last 5 years and only today it struck to me that the scripts which produce output without a trailing newline character, is not being displayed.

For example:

(1) This doesn't display any output: `echo -n "foo"`

```
.-(~)---------------------------(gazal@Admins-MBP)-
--> echo -n "foo"
.-(~)---------------------------(gazal@Admins-MBP)-
-->
```

(2) However, this works correctly: `echo "foo"`

```
.-(~)---------------------------(gazal@Admins-MBP)-
--> echo  "foo"
foo
.-(~)---------------------------(gazal@Admins-MBP)-
-->
```

To setup this, I simply did this

`autoload -Uz promptinit`

`promptinit`

`prompt adam2`

However, if I switch to adam1 or any other prompt, the issue as described in (1) does not happen.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `setopt prompt_sp` after you initialized the prompt, like so:

```
autoload -U promptinit
promptinit
prompt adam2 8bit
setopt prompt_sp
```

https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2017/msg00607.html